# Implementing radio button behavior using a switch in Nativescript (angular 2)

Tags: angular, data-binding, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to mimic radio button behavior in nativescript but am having issues with the binding. The code below almost works but if I "long tap" or kinda swipe one of the switches I don't believe the binding works, because it then doesn't deselect when I tap another switch.

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" *ngFor="let site of sites">
    <Label [text]="site.station_name" class="medium-spacing" (tap)="goToObserve()"></Label>
    <Switch text="" [checked]="isSiteSelected(site)" (tap)="toggleSite(site)"></Switch>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the component function

```
toggleSite(site) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        for(var s of this.sites) {
            if(s.station_id == site.station_id) {
                s.selected = true;
            }
            else {
                s.selected = false;
            }
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

Any ideas on a correct implementation? I've tried various iterations using [ngModel], and (propertyChange)="toggleSite(site)" but nothing seems to work. Also the setTimeout seems hacky, but without it the switch seemed like it was always one behind the toggle.

**Solution** I'm using based on @Nikolay Tsonev answer. I'm happy I could get rid of the setTimeout. It's probably incorrect that I pass both parameters to toggleSite($event, site) but it seems to work.

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
  <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="data-grid">
    <StackLayout class="grid-header" orientation="horizontal">
      <Label text="Sites" class="left-column" width="70%"></Label>
      <Label text="Selected" class="right-column" width="30%"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <ScrollView height="50%">
      <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" *ngFor="let site of sites" height="50">
          <Label text="{{ cameraIcon }}" (tap)="viewSitePhoto()" class="icon" width="10%"></Label>
          <Label [text]="site.station_name" class="medium-spacing" (tap)="viewSiteObservations()" width="60%" text-align="left"></Label>
          <Switch text="" [checked]="site.selected" (checkedChange)="toggleSite($event, site)" width="30%" text-align="right"></Switch>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and inside my component I have:

```
toggleSite(event, site) {
    let newSwitchValue = event.value;
    if(newSwitchValue) {
        for(var s of this.sites) {
            if(s.station_id == site.station_id) {
                s.selected = true;
            }
            else {
                s.selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Switch `checkedChange` event, which will notify you when the value of the component has been changed. I am attaching sample code. For further help you could review those example - [examples](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/switch).

app.component.html

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" >
    <Label text="station_name" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
    <Switch  checked="isSiteSelected" (checkedChange)="selectedvalueChanged($event)"></Switch>
</StackLayout>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    public counter: number = 16;

    public get message(): string {
        if (this.counter > 0) {
            return this.counter + " taps left";
        } else {
            return "Hoorraaay! \nYou are ready to start building!";
        }
    }

    public onTap() {
        this.counter--;
    }
     public selectedvalueChanged(args) {
         console.log(args.object.checked)

}
}
```